Sign of a complex number
My textbook says that $\sqrt{-27+36i} = \pm(3+6i)$. Why does the solution require a $\pm$, since $i$ does not have a sign? That is, $i$ isn't positive or negative, so what does the $\pm$ do in this context?

Well, if $z$ is a non-zero complex number then $z\neq -z$.  That said, it would probably be better to drop the radical notation and just speak of solutions to $z^2=\omega$ for fixed $\omega \in \mathbb C$.

In complex analysis, the $~\pm~$ sign indicates that you must multiply the expression by either $~+1,~$ or $~-1.~$  So, the two resulting expressions are $$(+1) \times (3 + 6i),~ \text{and}~(-1) \times (3 + 6i).$$  The idea is since $~w_0 = 1, ~$ and $~w_1 = -1~$ are the two roots of $~z^2 = 1,~$ you can apply either factor to $~(3 + 6i).$

$\pm z$ means $(\pm1)z$, while $w\pm z$ means $w+(\pm z)$.

Solutions to $x^2=-1$ are $x=\pm i$; that doesn’t mean $i$ is positive or negative

$-z$ does not mean "minus $z$" or "$z$ with a minus sign" or anything like that.
$-z$ means, instead, the additive inverse of $z$.
And the symbol $\pm z$ is just a shorthand for the two element set $\{z,-z\}$.
And what the equation $\sqrt{-27+36i} = \pm(3+6i)$ is telling you is that the solution set of the equation
$$z^2 = -27 + 36i
$$
is
$$\{3+6i, -(3+6i)\} \quad\text{which is equal to}\quad \{3+6i, -3-6i\}
$$

$-z$ kind of is "$z$ with a minus sign", though, isn't it? The point is that the minus sign means we're looking at the additive inverse of $z$. The minus sign does not mean we're looking at a negative number; it only means that if we put it in front of a number that is known to be positive, for example, $-2$. At least, that's how I look at it.

No, I’d suggest that it is misleading to think of $-z$ as “$z$ with a minus sign.” Think instead that it’s “$z$ with an ‘invert’ sign.”  Thus there are two signs (the unary ‘invert’ and the binary ‘minus’) that share a typographical symbol. It is absolutely true that we very often pronounce “$-z$” as “minus $z$,” but that is an abuse of terminology. Mathematicians know this perfectly well and are at no risk of being tripped up, but the general public often gets led astray by it.

I think this is actually a really good question.  One thing that tripped me up when learning complex numbers and complex analysis how negatives work, and maybe you’re stuck on the same concept.  Even though no one had told me to, I had mentally mapped negatives in real numbers to relative values, like $0$ is less than $1$ in the same way $-1$ is less than $0$.  Negatives are always less than positives, etc.  But negativity is an algebraic property:  $-5$ is the number that if you add it to $5$ you get $0$.
But the complex numbers can’t be totally ordered in a way that is compatible with the field operations, that is to say in a way that is compatible with using negative signs and such.  So you have to throw away any notion you have of signedness being part of an ordering.
In a very related way, we can’t think of a complex number as “positive” or “negative”.  But that doesn’t mean we can’t use negative signs to have the algebraic meaning.

Even in real numbers, you can't always infer relative values from a minus sign. For example, which is greater, $0$ or $-x$, where $x$ is a real number? It depends on whether $x$ itself is greater than, less than, or equal to $0$. Many students get tripped up by thinking of $-x$ as a "negative" number.

If you are familiar with graphing complex numbers in the (complex) plane, you’ll be able to see that $3 + 6i$ and $-(3 + 6i) = -3 - 6i$ lie on opposite sides of the origin $0 = 0 + 0i$ and at the same distance from it. This is exactly the same as how any nonzero real number and its opposite lie on either side of $0$ on the real line.
Where the unary (i.e. single-argument) operator “$-$” is being used (as it is here), you should think of it not as “negative,” but as “opposite.”
In any case, if you square either of $3+6i$ and $-3-6i$, you will see that the result is indeed $-27+36i$. And if you know what multiplication looks like in the complex plane, you’ll understand that since $-3-6i$ is $180$ degrees around from $3+6i$, the square of the former is $180 + 180 = 360$ degrees around from the square of the latter… thus coincident with (lying directly on top of) it. That’s another way to see that the squares are equal.

Saying "$i$ doesn't have a sign" is maybe not entirely correct. When we declare that $i$ is one of the solutions to $x^2 + 1 = 0$, we arbitrarily choose one of those two solutions to be $i$, and then that results in the other solution being $-i$. We need these to be distinct values since we want $i + i = 2i$ and $i + (-i) = 0$ to be two different equations.

I think most answers so far have been somewhat theoretical/philosophical but a more pragmatic approach can at the very least shed some light.
Let us say we have no clue what value $\sqrt{-27 + 36i}$ takes on. We suspect that it's probably a complex number, and so we can reasonably expect that $\sqrt{-27 + 36i} = a + bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. If it turns out that our $\sqrt{-27 + 36i}$ is not actually complex, then it's all good, because we'll find out that $b = 0$. This means, if we square both sides, we find that $$\sqrt{-27+36i} = a+bi \implies -27+36i=a^2-b^2+2abi.$$ Which gives us two equations. The first is $-27=a^2-b^2$ and the second is $18 = ab$. Rearrange the second equation to be $b = 18/a$ and substitute into the first to give us $-27 = a^2 - (18/a)^2$. You can spend some time massaging and rearranging this equation to obtain the expression $$ a^4+27a^2-324=0. $$A simple factorisation then yields that $$ (a^2+36)(a^2-9) =0. $$ Hence, taking any particular branch gives us exactly two solutions for the value of $a$, for four values in total. Either $a = \pm 6i$ or $a=\pm 3$.But we know that $a$ is a real number and so it is the case that $a=\pm 3$. Using this, substitute this value into $18=ab$ to give us that $b=\pm 6$. Combining it all together, we get that $\sqrt{-27+36i} = \pm3\pm 6i$.
The key takeaway is that the $\pm$ comes from calculating the magnitude of the imaginary component of our surd. It is simply a byproduct of the fact that calculating the square root entails that we end up solving a very simple quadratic equation which yields two solutions — a positive and a negative solution.

The formula
$$\sqrt{-27+36i} = \pm(3+6i) \tag{1}$$
does not mean that complex numbers have a sign. It simply expresses the fact that $+(3+6i) = 3+6i$ and $-(3+6i) = -3 - 6i$ are the two square roots of $-27+36i$.
Note that also real numbers $r > 0$ have two real square roots, a positive and a negative one. For example, $2$ and $-2$ are the square roots of $4$, and one can write this in the form $$\sqrt{4} = \pm2 \tag{2}.$$
It has to be emphasized that an expression of the form
$$\sqrt u = \pm v \tag{3}$$
with a non-zero real or complex number $u$ is no equation in the usual sense. Actually the equal sign in $(3)$ is an abuse of notation. It is just a symbolic way to say that
$$u \text{ has the two distinct square roots } +v = v \text{ and } -v \tag{4}.$$ Recall that a square root of $u$ is defined as a number $w$ such that $u = w^2$.
This also means that the symbol $\sqrt u$ in $(3)$ does not denote a number because one assigns to it two distinct values. Thus $(3)$ is misleading in the sense that it seems to be an equation between  numbers - but as we have seen, this is not true. It is a short cut for $(4)$.
A more formal way to understand the symbol $\sqrt u$ is to regard it as the two-element set $\{+v = v, -v\}$. Then $(3)$ reads as
$$\sqrt u = \{+v , -v\} . \tag{3'}$$
In the real case one usually avoids ambiguity in the interpretation of the square root symbol via the convention that the symbol $\sqrt r$ stands for the positive square root. This is a very natural choice - nevertheless it is an arbitrary choice. One could alternatively define $\sqrt r $ to be the negative square root or even make an "erratic choice" of a square root for each $r$ individually.
The standard convention gives a (single-valued!) square root function $\sqrt{ \phantom{x}} : [0,\infty \to [0,\infty)$. Note that this function is continuous. As explained above, one could alternatively understand $\sqrt{ \phantom{x}} $ as a set-valued function assigning to $0$ the one-element set $\{0\}$ and to $r > 0$ the two-element set consisting of the positive and negative square root of $r$.
Also in the complex case one could make a convention which assigns to $z \in \mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ one of its two square roots so that the symbol $\sqrt z$ would stand for a unique complex number. This involves again a choice, but it cannot be made as natural as the choice in the real case.
For example, define $\mathbb C^*_1$ as the union the open upper half-plane $\{x + iy \mid y > 0\}$ and the positive real axis $\{x+iy \mid x > 0 \text{ and }\ y = 0 \}$. This set has the property that for each $w \ne 0$ exactly one of the two numbers $w, -w$ is contained in $\mathbb C^*_1$. Now define $\sqrt z$ to be that square root of $z$ lying in $\mathbb C^*_1$. This produces a single-valued function $\sqrt{ \phantom{x}} : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, but it is easy to see that it is discontinuous at the points of the positive real axis (which is rather unpleasant). However, it has the benefit that it agrees with the "standard" real square root function on $[0,\infty)$.
One can construct many other single-valued functions $\sqrt{ \phantom{x}} : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, but one can prove that none of them is continuous.
Anyway, it has to be emphasized that for complex numbers $z \ne 0$ there is no standard interpretation of $\sqrt z$ as a complex number.
